# Android: Horizontal scrollviewer incorrect width. Not wide enough

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have a layout, made from code like the following:

HorizontalScrollViewer -> ListView -> TableView.

The table has multiple columns and looks like a classic datagrid (like Excel).
The grid is in total about 2500px width: listview.getWidth().
The horizontal scrollviewer is "stuck" at 1400px width.

So I can scroll a part of my listview but not completely. 
When I turn my phone (Samsung S7, Android 7) in landscape, the gridView is completely visible and horizontal scrolling is not needed.

In the an Android 6.0 Emulator the horizontalScrollviewer works correctly and I can see all the columns...

The width of the horizontalScrollviewer is not correctly calculated somehow but I don't know how to set this and I can't explain why it works in the emulator.

I am new to Android developing so I might miss some basic things..!

Any help is very appreciated!

Code:

```
_view = new LinearLayout(context);
_view.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
_horizontalScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(context);
_horizontalScrollView.setFillViewport(true);
 _horizontalScrollView.setLayoutParams(new     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

//Code that fills the listview with a table with some columns (TextViews)

_horizontalScrollView.addView(_listView);
_view.addView(_horizontalScrollView);
```

Comment: without your code we can't help you. Please post it

Comment: Thanks!
I updated my post.

Comment: You said "HorizontalScrollViewer -> ListView -> TableView" , but where is your ListView and TableView into your code?

Comment: This library should help you. https://github.com/zhouchaoyuan/excelPanel